# Refreshing PATH variable after deleting file in /etc/profile.d

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

Custom path is added using a file in /etc/profile.d. but when the file is deleted, Need to update/refresh the PATH environment variable without logout/login to system for the changes to be seen.

To add a new path to PATH environment variable, I have created a file test.sh in /etc/profile.d. Contents of test.sh is

Export PATH=$PATH:/new/path

When I want to remove this custom path ,I delete the test.sh file. But the PATH environment variable is still showing /new/path.

The changes are reflected only on logoff/login. Is there a way to refresh the PATH without doing logoff login?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402091/reload-environment-variables-without-relogin-to-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Just only remove the strin/new/path in the $PATH.
export  PATH=$(echo $PATH|sed 's//new/path//g')

Comment: I want the changes to be reflected system wide. Export will only change for current terminal. On deleting the file in /etc/profile.d the newly added path should be deleted. But the Path is updated only on logoff and login. I wanted a way to reflect the changes without logout-login